# Simple Django form / model save question

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to set the BooleanField `inuse` to True when I save the ModelForm (I'm using a form outside of the admin area) and I'm unsure how to do it.

Models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inuse = models.BooleanField()

class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Your name*:")
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True, null=True)
```

Forms:

```
class BookingForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Booking

        def save(self, commit=True):
            booking = super(BookingForm, self).save(commit=False)
            if commit:
                booking.save()
                self.save_m2m()
                for location in booking.place.all():
                    location.inuse = True
                    print location #nothing prints
                    location.save()
```

View:

```
def booking(request):
    form = BookingForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form = form

        return render_to_response('bookingform.html', {
                'form': form,
            })
```

Updated to latest (see [Manoj Govindan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652585/simple-django-form-model-save-question/3653016#3653016)).  It is still not updating `inuse` to True on submit / save.

Comment: Are there any other models involved? What is the underlying model for `Booking` form? What is the relationship between `Location` and other models if any?

Comment: no relationship other than what you see minus some meta etc

Comment: What's wrong with `models.BooleanField(default=True)`?

Comment: The locations are added by the admins with False and I only want them to be update to True when the user selects them on the Booking form.

Answer (score 3):

```
class BookingForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Booking

    def save(self, commit=True):
        booking = super(BookingForm, self).save(commit=False)
        booking.inuse = True
        if commit:
            booking.save()
```

Comment: @Daniel: shouldn't it be `Location.inuse`? According to the OP `Booking` is a _form_.

Comment: Looking promising but gives me...TypeError at /

super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Comment: @Rob B: try replacing `booking = super(Booking, self).save(commit=False)` with `booking = super(BookingForm, self).save(commit=False)`

Comment: @Manoj Govindan that solved my error message but looking in admin the Location value hasn't updated to true when I submit the form.

Comment: @Rob B: is the underlying model of the form `Booking` or `Location`? Daniel's answer presumes that it is `Booking`; but I do not see such a model in your question.

Comment: I presume that `Booking` is a *model*, not a form, especially as it has model fields rather than form fields.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman yes Booking is a model - there was a typo in the code above I've corrected.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is my stab at it:

```
class BookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking

    def save(self, commit=True):
        booking = super(BookingForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            booking.save()  
            self.save_m2m()
            for location in booking.place.all():
                location.inuse = True
                location.save()
```

**Update**

Entire code I've used:

```
# models.py
class Location(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inuse = models.BooleanField()

class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Your name*:")
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True, null=True)

# forms.py
class BookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking

    def save(self, commit=True):
        booking = super(BookingForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            booking.save()
            self.save_m2m()
            for location in booking.place.all():
                location.inuse = True
                location.save()

In [1]: from test_app.forms import BookingForm
In [2]: from test_app.models import Location

# I had already saved some `Location` instances.

In [3]: data = dict(name = 'MyCity', place = [p.id for p in Location.objects.all()])
In [4]: f = BookingForm(data)
In [5]: f.save()
In [6]: for each in Location.objects.all():
   ...:     print each.place, each.inuse
   ...:      
PlaceA True 
PlaceB True 
PlaceC True
```

Comment: doesn't bring up any errors just doesn't update the location value to True on save

Comment: nope still no luck.  Doesn't error but doesn't seem to do anything either

Comment: Got it working. See above. The trick is to call `self.save_m2m()` explicitly to save the m2m objects.

Comment: can you paste in the entire model so I can compare?  I've tripled checked and its not working

Comment: @Manoj Govindan Thanks.  Still no luck. Would my view affect anything?