# ManyToMany field is not assigned in pre_(post_)save trigger

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-orm

I'm trying to work with ManyToMany field in post_save trigger.
an Example

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post, dispatch_uid='update_post_images')
def update_post_images(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
   post_save.disconnect(update_post_images, sender=Post, dispatch_uid='update_post_images')
   print 'before', instance.images.all()
   img = Image.object.get(pk=1469)
   instance.images.add(img)
   print 'after', instance.images.all()
   post_save.connect(update_post_images, sender=Post, dispatch_uid='update_post_images')
```

Now when i look to django console I see exactly what i want. The `print 'before'` outputs one image object and `print 'after'` - 2 objects
But when I query the same post object from python console (manage.py shell) I see that there is only one Image.

Please someone tell me what is wrng with this trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ManyToManyFields act differently than other fields with signals. Check out the [m2m_changed Signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) and run your logic on that signal instead of the post_save Signal.

Comment: I think that is not what I need. Once more I need to populate some values to ManytoMany field in post_save trigger. For example user changed text field in model Post. in post_save I'm parsing text for img tags and populate Post.images - field with those values

Comment: After some investigation i've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432385/django-how-to-save-m2m-data-via-post-save-signal link and it worked just fine. So you were right indeed