# Why django m2m Group.permission clear when adding permission in post_sav signal?

Tags: django-models, django-signals

In AdminSite, when adding permissions just after I received a post_save signal from a **class Groupe** which inherit from **django.contrib.auth.models.Group**:

```
def create_groupe(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:

        from django.db.models import Q
        if instance.role == 'OPERATOR':
            grp = Groupe.objects.get(name=instance)
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(FileDeposit)
            permissions = Permission.objects.filter(Q(content_type=content_type), Q(codename__startswith='view_') | Q(codename__startswith='download_'))
            grp.permissions = permissions

signals.post_save.connect(create_groupe, sender=Groupe)
```

It seems the Group.permission m2m is updated with new permissions and then the Manager of Groupe (or Group) call his clear() method.

I've seen this with another signal change_m2m:

```
signals.m2m_changed.connect(m2m_group, sender=Groupe.permissions.through)
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432385/django-how-to-save-m2m-data-via-post-save-signal#comment4839446_4432385] The solution of my problems seems connected to this one,  but I don't know how to find a workaround, any ideas ?