# Add method doesnt work when trying to establish m2m relationships using post_save in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

My `Content` model has a `many-to-many` relationship to the `Tag` model. When I save a `Content` object, I want to add the relationships dynamically. I'm doing this the following way.

```
def tag_content(obj):
    for tag in Tag.objects.all():
        print tag
        obj.tags.add(tag)
    obj.is_tagged = True
    obj.save()

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_tagged = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender = Content)
def update_m2m_relationships_on_save(sender, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs['instance'].is_tagged:
        tag_content(kwargs['instance'])
```

The `tag_content` function runs, however, the `m2m` relationships are not established. Im using Django 1.9.8 btw. This makes no sense. What am I missing? Moreover, if I do something like `tag_content(content_instance)` in shell, then the tags are set, so the function is ok. I guess the problem is in the receiver. Any help?

*Edit*

My question has nothing to do with m2m_changed, as I have said, creating a Content object in shell works perfectly. Therefore, the problem lies in the admin panel's setup.

Comment: Can you verify that the `update_m2m_relationships_on_save` is being called and that it's receiving the correct kwargs? That's how I'd debug it personally.  Cause you've seemed to verify all the other pieces...

Comment: Yep. The `print tag` does exactly that and yes, the save method is calling the update_m2m method.

Comment: Try printing `kwargs['instance']` and `kwargs['instance'].is_tagged` before the `if` statement in your receiver to make sure the object and boolean are both what you'd expect

Comment: I've tried that too, and I do get the correct instance.

Comment: If it wasn't saving at least the 'is_tagged' field, it would be a feedback loop because you are calling save again. And it would loop forever. So if it prints out the tags (as you've claimed) and the `obj` is the correct one, and it's not looping forever. It's saving. Is it possible you are then checking stale data (from the shell for example). I had this happen to me a few days ago... Just re-get the item after this is ran to double check. (worth a try!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - How to save m2m data via post\_save signal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432385/django-how-to-save-m2m-data-via-post-save-signal)

Comment: The kwargs, is_tagged fields are the correct ones. I tested them using print commands. Still, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem. Basically, this has something to do with how Django handles its form in the admin panel. When trying to add the Contents from admin, I kept the tags field empty, thinking the tag_content function would handle it. However, that is exactly where the problem was, as creating a Content from shell tagged it just fine. In other words, changing the admin panel to something like this solved my problem :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import *
from django import forms

class ContentCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('title',)

class ContentChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('title', 'is_tagged', 'tags')

class ContentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj is None:
            return ContentCreationForm
        else:
            return ContentChangeForm


admin.site.register(Tag)
admin.site.register(Content, ContentAdmin)
```

When trying to create a new Content, only the 'title' field is presented. This solves the problem.